# Remapping keys in KeyRemap4MacBook, how do I find keycodes?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

I'm currently remapping some of the keys on my MacBook using KeyRemap4Macbook - in that process I need to remap the keys using this xml-file, namely private.xml, that is referenced here:http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en

This is an example of how private.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Swap Space and Tab</name>
    <identifier>private.swap_space_and_tab</identifier>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::SPACE, KeyCode::TAB</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::TAB, KeyCode::SPACE</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Does anyone know where I find a chart of the keycodes referenced in the XML, the capitalized words (SPACE, TAB)?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202629/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-mac-virtual-key-codes) answer, key codes which you are looking for are:

kVK_Tab                       = 0x30,
  kVK_Space                     = 0x31,

See lines 269, 270.

Also there is an [application](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) which can show you key codes in a more friendly way.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the "basic"-tab on the linked webpage, shows a link (List of KeyCode) to a [KeyCode.data](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data)-file on their GitHub repository.